# Decimal Input Values

Tags: vba, visual-studio, datagridview, decimal

I have to accept 6 digit decimal numbers from users and store it to make some calculation in the future. Users will write decimal numbers on datagridview cells. (Because there is a list of numbers to enter). So the problem is that; how can i be sure thet the user entered the acceptable 6 digit decimal number? For example 0.000012 will be the number. But some computers use 0,000012 for seperator. Or user may enter some kind of data that is not a decimal number, so program must warn him. So is there any good way to get decimal numbers from users on datagridview?

Comment: are you talking about [tag:ms-access]?

Comment: ...or do you mean VB.NET? (which is not VBA)

Comment: Yes I Use Visual Basic 2010 Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataGridView.CellValueChanged event and get the users input. First try "IsNumeric" to check if its numerical input. Then use CDbl to change the format to 6 digit decimal number.